# Override CSS with dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to use the CSS override values #bigbox and #bigbox-window only when the drop menu is not equal to Standings or Select a Location...

This is my first post, forgive any formatting errors! Thanks!

```
<html>
  <style>
    #bigbox { height:680px; }
    #bigbox-window { height:680px; }
  </style>      
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function setIframeSource() { 
      var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
      var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
      var theUrl;

      theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
      theIframe.src = theUrl;
    }

  </script>
  <body>
    <div class="page page-pick_em">
      <h1>College Hockey Pick 'Em League</h1>
      <form id="form1" method="post">
        <label>
          <select id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
            <option value="">Select a location ...</option> 
            <option value="page/pick_em/standings.html">Standings</option> 
            <option value="page/pick_em/week01.html">Week 01</option> 
            <option value="page/pick_em/week02.html">Week 02</option> 
          </select>
        </label>
      </form>
      <iframe SRC="page/pick_em/standings.html" width="100%" height="80%" id="myIframe" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" onLoad="autoResize('myIframe');"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Just for your own future reference, Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: "forgive any formatting errors" - or, you could doublecheck your formatting using the ever so helpful preview, and hit the editing help to fix it.

Comment: Also: what have you tried? What should the override classes be applied to? Why include `setIFrameSource()` in your code sample when it doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question?

Comment: Are you avoiding jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this changes the CSS when the dropdowns are not the options you specified in the question.

Since I don't know where you're using `bigbox` and `bigbox-window`, and what you want to change in those styles, just follow my example and adapt it to your needs.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/2Ew2M/1)

```
theOptText = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].text;
if ((theOptText != "Select a location ...") && (theOptText != "Standings"))
{
    document.getElementById("bigbox").style.borderColor = "#f00";
}
```